# How does a Spring web controller determine the HTTP status code for a redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application that has an endpoint that results in a redirect - see code below.

I notice that the HTTP status code that Spring returns for this redirect is a `307`. My question is why does Spring choose to return a `307`  rather than a `301` or a `302`.

Is it simply the fact that both `GET` and `POST` methods are allowed on this endpoint and `307` is the least permissive response in terms of what a client can do so Spring implements that as the default?

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String loginAttemptWithoutCookie() {
    return "redirect:" + "/some/other/url;
}
```

Comment: 302 has been superseded (replaced by) either 303 or 307. Hence a 307 in newer versions of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

**All modern browser will automatically detect 302**

**302**

Actually all HTTP response status codes that are in the `3xx` category are considered 
redirection message, all modern browser will automatically detect `302` Found  response code and process the temporarily redirection action automatically

**307**

actually `307` Internal Redirect from admin side 
client click on cart items then browser  sent a POST to /cart-items.html, then this tells it to redirect the POST at /purchase-selected-items.php

The mean is, Spring is trying to redirect custom defined( view already created by admin  ) view without default redirection